# Highcharts doesn't display bars properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

My Highchart doesn't display bars scattered even if they have different values. What's going wrong?

My JSON data:

```json
[  
    {  
        "name":"finwts_main  -1",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431160907000,
                "to":1431160955000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"finwts_main  -2",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431160966000,
                "to":1431160984000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"finwts_main  -3",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431160994000,
                "to":1431161314000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"impr_main  -prod",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431161334000,
                "to":1431171728000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"taxupdt_th  -P",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431174835000,
                "to":1431175557000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"sp_basic_entities_driver  -prod",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431177337000,
                "to":1431177818000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"basic_main  -HYBR",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431177830000,
                "to":1431178155000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"basic_main  -SUPR",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431178163000,
                "to":1431178341000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"basic_main  -CESCPI",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431178348000,
                "to":1431178484000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"agg_main  -HYBR",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431180464000,
                "to":1431181001000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"agg_main  -CESCPI",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431181008000,
                "to":1431181247000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"supr_agg_main  -SUPR",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431182033000,
                "to":1431183111000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"msa_main  -prod",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431181253000,
                "to":1431182027000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"sp_est_pop_mars_indx ",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431183115000,
                "to":1431183135000,
                "label":"completed",
                "color":"#63CA00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"cellrelpr_main  -PRICING",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"",
        "st_time_am_pm":" pm",
        "ed_time_am_pm":"",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":1431184142000,
                "to":1431184142000,
                "label":"<b>**processing**</b>",
                "color":"#00BFFF"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"avgpr_main  -F",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":107,
                "to":108,
                "label":" ",
                "color":"#999999"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"avgpr_main  -U",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":107,
                "to":108,
                "label":" ",
                "color":"#999999"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"avgpr_main  -M",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":107,
                "to":108,
                "label":" ",
                "color":"#999999"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"compstat_main  -prod",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":107,
                "to":108,
                "label":" ",
                "color":"#999999"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"sp_est_pop_mars_calc  - ",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":107,
                "to":108,
                "label":" ",
                "color":"#999999"
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "name":"sp_est_pop_effect_dissem  - ",
        "st_date":"04/9/2015",
        "ed_date":"04/9/2015",
        "st_time_am_pm":" am",
        "ed_time_am_pm":" am",
        "intervals":[  
            {  
                "from":107,
                "to":108,
                "label":" ",
                "color":"#999999"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Demonstration below:

```js
$(function() {


   //split time record for yAxsis
   var timeforchartandgrid = '';

   function timsesubstringforXaxis(timechart) {

       var res = timechart;


       // var dateres = timechart.substring(0, 10);
       var timeArray = res.split(':');
       var hours = timeArray[0];
       var minutes = timeArray[1];
       var secnds = timeArray[2];

       if (hours == 12) {
         hours = 12;
       } else if (hours > 12) {
         hours = '0' + hours % 12;
       } else {
         hours = hours;
       }

       timeforchartandgrid = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + secnds;
       return timeforchartandgrid;

     }
     //,{"name" :"avgpr_main  -F","st_date" :"10/1/2014","ed_date" :"10/1/2014","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 53865000,"to": 54006000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]}
   var arraylist = '[{"name" :"finwts_main  -1","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 1431160907000,"to": 1431160955000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"finwts_main  -2","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 1431160966000,"to": 1431160984000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"finwts_main  -3","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 1431160994000,"to": 1431161314000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"impr_main  -prod","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 1431161334000,"to": 1431171728000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"taxupdt_th  -P","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431174835000,"to": 1431175557000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"sp_basic_entities_driver  -prod","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431177337000,"to": 1431177818000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"basic_main  -HYBR","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431177830000,"to": 1431178155000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"basic_main  -SUPR","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431178163000,"to": 1431178341000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"basic_main  -CESCPI","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431178348000,"to": 1431178484000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"agg_main  -HYBR","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431180464000,"to": 1431181001000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"agg_main  -CESCPI","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431181008000,"to": 1431181247000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"supr_agg_main  -SUPR","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431182033000,"to": 1431183111000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"msa_main  -prod","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431181253000,"to": 1431182027000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"sp_est_pop_mars_indx ","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm","intervals": [{ "from": 1431183115000,"to": 1431183135000,"label": "completed","color" : "#63CA00"}]},{"name" :"cellrelpr_main  -PRICING","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"","st_time_am_pm" :" pm","ed_time_am_pm" :"","intervals": [{ "from": 1431184142000,"to": 1431184142000,"label": "<b>**processing**</b>","color" : "#00BFFF"}]},{"name" :"avgpr_main  -F","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 107,"to": 108,"label": " ","color" : "#999999"}]},{"name" :"avgpr_main  -U","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 107,"to": 108,"label": " ","color" : "#999999"}]},{"name" :"avgpr_main  -M","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 107,"to": 108,"label": " ","color" : "#999999"}]},{"name" :"compstat_main  -prod","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 107,"to": 108,"label": " ","color" : "#999999"}]},{"name" :"sp_est_pop_mars_calc  - ","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 107,"to": 108,"label": " ","color" : "#999999"}]},{"name" :"sp_est_pop_effect_dissem  - ","st_date" :"04/9/2015","ed_date" :"04/9/2015","st_time_am_pm" :" am","ed_time_am_pm" :" am","intervals": [{ "from": 107,"to": 108,"label": " ","color" : "#999999"}]}]';

   var tasks = jQuery.parseJSON(arraylist);


   var series = [];
   var categories = [];

   //alert(tasks[i].st_time_am_pm);
   $.each(tasks.reverse(), function(i, task) {
     var item = {
       name: task.name,
       data: []

     };
     $.each(task.intervals, function(j, interval) {
       item.data.push({
         x: interval.from,
         y: i,
         label: interval.label,
         color: interval.color,
         from: interval.from,
         to: interval.to
       }, {
         x: interval.to,
         y: i,
         from: interval.from,
         to: interval.to

       });

       // add a null value between intervals
       if (task.intervals[j + 1]) {
         item.data.push(
           [(interval.to + task.intervals[j + 1].from) / 2, null]);
       }

     });

     series.push(item);
   });

   //try catch block 2



   //           // restructure the milestones
   //           $.each(milestones, function (i, milestone) {
   //                 var item = Highcharts.extend(milestone, {
   //                                data: [[
   //                        milestone.time,
   //                        milestone.task
   //                    ]],
   //                                type: 'scatter'
   //                            });
   //                            series.push(item);
   //             });


   // create the chart
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

     chart: {
       renderTo: 'container'
     },

     title: {
       //message_for_expected_finish_time
     },
     subtitle: {

     },

     credits: {
       enabled: false
     },
     xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
       //type: 'timepicker',
       tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12,
       labels: {

         style: {
           color: '#525151',
           font: '14px Arial',
           fontWeight: 'bold'
         },
         formatter: function() {

           var mycharttime = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%P', this.value);

           return timsesubstringforXaxis(mycharttime);
         }
       },
       maxPadding: 0.2,
       //min: start_chart_scale_dt,
       // max: end_chart_scale_dt,
       // minTickInterval:200
       title: {
         // text: displayMonthXaxiesTitle,
         align: 'low'
       }
     },

     yAxis: {
       tickInterval: 1,
       labels: {

         style: {
           color: '#525151',
           font: '14px Arial',
           fontWeight: 'bold'
         },
         formatter: function() {
           if (tasks[this.value]) {
             return tasks[this.value].name;
           }
         }
       },
       startOnTick: false,
       endOnTick: false,
       title: {
         text: 'Job Task Names'
       },

       maxPadding: 0.1
     },

     legend: {
       enabled: false
     },

     txooltip: {
       crosshairs: [false, true],
       formatter: function() {

         //if label is undefined 
         //if (isNaN(this.point.options.label)) {
         //  return ;
         //};

         //                            if (this.series.data[0].label == "not started") {
         //                                return '<b>Job Name: </b>' + tasks[this.y].name + '<br/>' +
         //                          '<b>Job Status: </b>' + this.point.options.label + '<br/>';
         //                            };
         //tool tip for processing job
         if (this.series.data[0].label == "not started") {
           return '<b>Job Name: </b>' + tasks[this.y].name + '<br/>' +
             '<b>Job Status: </b>' + this.series.data[0].label + '<br/>';
         };

         if (this.series.data[0].label == "<b>**processing**</b>") {
           return '<b>Job Name: </b>' + tasks[this.y].name + '<br/>' +
             '<b>Job Status: </b>' + this.series.data[0].label + '<br/>';

         };
         //tool tip for completed job
         if (this.series.data[0].label == "completed") {

           var testgridst = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.point.options.from) + ' ' + tasks[this.y].st_time_am_pm;
           var testgrided = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.point.options.to) + ' ' + tasks[this.y].ed_time_am_pm;;


           return '<b>Job Name: </b>' + tasks[this.y].name + '<br/>' +
             '<b>Job Status: </b>' + this.series.data[0].label + '<br/>' +
             '<b>Job Start Time: </b>' + testgridst + '<br/>' +
             '<b>Job End Time: </b>' + testgrided; // +' ' + tasks[this.y].ed_time_am_pm;
         };
       }
     },

     plotOptions: {
       line: {
         turboThreshold: 6000000,
         lineWidth: 8,
         //color: jb_selected_color,
         marker: {
           enabled: false
         },
         dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           align: 'left',
           borderRadius: 5,
           backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',
           borderWidth: 1,
           borderColor: '#AAA',
           y: -6,
           formatter: function() {
             return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
           }
         }
       }
     },

     exporting: {
       enabled: false
     },
     series: series,
     animation: {
       duration: 6000
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/14/).

Comment: Please, provide information what exactly is wrong with your chart. And what results are expected.

Comment: I guess that you would like to have "yellow" labels in the same line as scatter, correct? If yes, defaulty datalabels are above point, so you need to use x/y parameter to align datalabel and set verticalAlign as middle.

Comment: The question is , bars has different "from" and "to" json values but they appears on the same xAxis  .  it shoul be appeared on diferent xAxis.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8yt602nj/1/  this is updated one .. there is a bar called not started , I want it to start at the beginning  of the chart. I tried to change json value but no luck.

Comment: this is the code which gives the 'not started'  bar st time and ed time  st_time = Date.UTC(parseInt(year1, 10), parseInt(month1, 10), parseInt(day1, 10), parseInt(hour1, 10), parseInt(min1, 10), parseInt(sec1, 10));
                    ed_time = st_time + 10;

Comment: Well, bars are printed according to data which you supply. Could you send me a screentshot / mockup how it should be printed?